# Alternate locations for /tmp/.X11-unix?

Tags: xorg

Does `/tmp/.X11-unix`, the directory that contains the UNIX sockets for communicating with the X server, ever have a different location (like because of some strange distro)?  If so, is there any way of finding the alternate location?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it's possible that that default is hardcoded somewhere in the `xorg` source, possibly in one of the core `libx11-` libraries that every program that might want to communicate with the X server loads. I recommend going through the source tree with `find` and `grep`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The online source code for the latest X11 *Release 7.7
6 June 2012* is available as several tar files. The source [tar](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/src/lib/libX11-1.5.0.tar.gz) for libX11 shows us in file `libX11-1.5.0/src/OpenDis.c` the implementation of routine `XOpenDisplay()`. It calls `_XConnectXCB()` in adjacent file `xcb_disp.c` to start the connection. This calls `xcb_connect()`. The [tar](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/src/xcb/libxcb-1.8.1.tar.gz) for libxcb has that function in `libxcb-1.8.1/src/xcb_util.c`. It calls `_xcb_open()` in the same file which has the line

```
static const char unix_base[] = "/tmp/.X11-unix/X";
```

This line is not changed by any configuration option, though there is the use of `/tmp/launch` as a base if you `HAVE_LAUNCHD`, which I don't know anything about, and `/var/tsol/doors/.X11-unix/X` on Solaris Trusted Extensions.

There is nothing to stop a distribution patching these sources, of course. You can probably check your distribution with

```
strings /usr/lib*/libxcb.so|grep X11
```

which on my Fedora certainly shows `/tmp/.X11-unix/X`.

Answer (score 2):

If the X server (I assume Xorg) is running you should be able to find the socket like this: `sudo lsof -p $(pidof Xorg) | grep unix`